# Keras - Variable batch size for stateful LSTM

Tags: pandas, keras, time-series, lstm

I have a list of 986 arrays generated using the below line to select the Weeks only

```
weeks = [g for n, g in m15.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datebuff',freq='W'))]
```

I need two achieve two things. First, prepare the X_train and y_train, the X_train is gonna be each array excluding window size from the end. and y_train is the shift of the window size till the end of each array. *still researching*

Second, is there a way and the most important, is there a way to train LSTM, on each array separately, like feed it ? is it going to be the stateful loop ?

```
[               datebuff    High     Low    Open   Close
 0   2000-01-03 00:00:00  1.0080  1.0073  1.0073  1.0077
 1   2000-01-03 00:15:00  1.0087  1.0076  1.0078  1.0086
 2   2000-01-03 00:30:00  1.0089  1.0079  1.0087  1.0079
 3   2000-01-03 00:45:00  1.0132  1.0078  1.0078  1.0128
 4   2000-01-03 01:00:00  1.0133  1.0120  1.0129  1.0122
 5   2000-01-03 01:15:00  1.0125  1.0120  1.0123  1.0124
 6   2000-01-03 01:30:00  1.0137  1.0129  1.0132  1.0133
 7   2000-01-03 01:45:00  1.0141  1.0133  1.0135  1.0137
 8   2000-01-03 02:00:00  1.0145  1.0134  1.0140  1.0138
 9   2000-01-03 02:15:00  1.0142  1.0135  1.0135  1.0141
 10  2000-01-03 02:30:00  1.0147  1.0137  1.0142  1.0145
 11  2000-01-03 02:45:00  1.0173  1.0142  1.0142  1.0171
 12  2000-01-03 03:00:00  1.0190  1.0170  1.0170  1.0185
 13  2000-01-03 03:15:00  1.0189  1.0176  1.0188  1.0180
 14  2000-01-03 03:30:00  1.0183  1.0173  1.0180  1.0180
 15  2000-01-03 03:45:00  1.0180  1.0173  1.0179  1.0175
 16  2000-01-03 04:00:00  1.0177  1.0164  1.0173  1.0171
 17  2000-01-03 04:15:00  1.0171  1.0165  1.0167  1.0170
 18  2000-01-03 04:30:00  1.0171  1.0166  1.0166  1.0168
 19  2000-01-03 04:45:00  1.0171  1.0166  1.0167  1.0167
 20  2000-01-03 05:00:00  1.0171  1.0165  1.0171  1.0165
 21  2000-01-03 05:15:00  1.0171  1.0164  1.0171  1.0167
 22  2000-01-03 05:30:00  1.0168  1.0165  1.0168  1.0167
 23  2000-01-03 05:45:00  1.0172  1.0166  1.0166  1.0169
 24  2000-01-03 06:00:00  1.0180  1.0167  1.0171  1.0178
 25  2000-01-03 06:15:00  1.0181  1.0175  1.0181  1.0175
 26  2000-01-03 06:30:00  1.0179  1.0172  1.0177  1.0172
 27  2000-01-03 06:45:00  1.0177  1.0170  1.0173  1.0170
 28  2000-01-03 07:00:00  1.0174  1.0158  1.0174  1.0163
 29  2000-01-03 07:15:00  1.0167  1.0160  1.0163  1.0165
 ..                  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
 448 2000-01-07 16:30:00  1.0313  1.0299  1.0306  1.0299
 449 2000-01-07 16:45:00  1.0307  1.0288  1.0298  1.0292
 450 2000-01-07 17:00:00  1.0305  1.0284  1.0293  1.0304
 451 2000-01-07 17:15:00  1.0306  1.0288  1.0304  1.0297
 452 2000-01-07 17:30:00  1.0306  1.0294  1.0295  1.0303
 453 2000-01-07 17:45:00  1.0306  1.0293  1.0303  1.0293
 454 2000-01-07 18:00:00  1.0299  1.0289  1.0299  1.0293
 455 2000-01-07 18:15:00  1.0299  1.0292  1.0295  1.0297
 456 2000-01-07 18:30:00  1.0300  1.0280  1.0297  1.0280
 457 2000-01-07 18:45:00  1.0302  1.0281  1.0283  1.0299
 458 2000-01-07 19:00:00  1.0306  1.0293  1.0297  1.0293
 459 2000-01-07 19:15:00  1.0299  1.0290  1.0293  1.0292
 460 2000-01-07 19:30:00  1.0294  1.0284  1.0292  1.0287
 461 2000-01-07 19:45:00  1.0293  1.0285  1.0286  1.0289
 462 2000-01-07 20:00:00  1.0289  1.0280  1.0286  1.0283
 463 2000-01-07 20:15:00  1.0284  1.0273  1.0279  1.0275
 464 2000-01-07 20:30:00  1.0284  1.0275  1.0276  1.0283
 465 2000-01-07 20:45:00  1.0289  1.0272  1.0284  1.0281
 466 2000-01-07 21:00:00  1.0289  1.0279  1.0280  1.0281
 467 2000-01-07 21:15:00  1.0288  1.0276  1.0277  1.0277
 468 2000-01-07 21:30:00  1.0290  1.0276  1.0276  1.0287
 469 2000-01-07 21:45:00  1.0298  1.0289  1.0292  1.0294
 470 2000-01-07 22:00:00  1.0294  1.0287  1.0292  1.0291
 471 2000-01-07 22:15:00  1.0292  1.0284  1.0290  1.0287
 472 2000-01-07 22:30:00  1.0298  1.0289  1.0289  1.0296
 473 2000-01-07 22:45:00  1.0299  1.0295  1.0295  1.0295
 474 2000-01-07 23:00:00  1.0297  1.0292  1.0292  1.0294
 475 2000-01-07 23:15:00  1.0298  1.0294  1.0298  1.0297
 476 2000-01-07 23:30:00  1.0299  1.0299  1.0299  1.0299
 477 2000-01-07 23:45:00  1.0300  1.0298  1.0300  1.0298

 [478 rows x 5 columns],
                datebuff    High     Low    Open   Close
 478 2000-01-10 00:00:00  1.0298  1.0286  1.0286  1.0298
 479 2000-01-10 00:15:00  1.0300  1.0292  1.0297  1.0300
 480 2000-01-10 00:30:00  1.0301  1.0300  1.0301  1.0300
 481 2000-01-10 00:45:00  1.0305  1.0297  1.0305  1.0297
 482 2000-01-10 01:00:00  1.0298  1.0289  1.0295  1.0291
 483 2000-01-10 01:15:00  1.0302  1.0289  1.0294  1.0301
 484 2000-01-10 01:30:00  1.0302  1.0287  1.0300  1.0291
 485 2000-01-10 01:45:00  1.0293  1.0282  1.0290  1.0283
 486 2000-01-10 02:00:00  1.0287  1.0274  1.0282  1.0284
 487 2000-01-10 02:15:00  1.0292  1.0280  1.0283  1.0284
 488 2000-01-10 02:30:00  1.0290  1.0284  1.0287  1.0286
 489 2000-01-10 02:45:00  1.0292  1.0285  1.0287  1.0289
 490 2000-01-10 03:00:00  1.0291  1.0283  1.0291  1.0289
 491 2000-01-10 03:15:00  1.0292  1.0285  1.0291  1.0286
 492 2000-01-10 03:30:00  1.0292  1.0283  1.0289  1.0289
 493 2000-01-10 03:45:00  1.0301  1.0288  1.0290  1.0289
 494 2000-01-10 04:00:00  1.0295  1.0289  1.0290  1.0290
 495 2000-01-10 04:15:00  1.0298  1.0289  1.0291  1.0292
 496 2000-01-10 04:30:00  1.0295  1.0292  1.0293  1.0293
 497 2000-01-10 04:45:00  1.0295  1.0292  1.0294  1.0293
 498 2000-01-10 05:00:00  1.0295  1.0292  1.0292  1.0292
 499 2000-01-10 05:15:00  1.0294  1.0290  1.0291  1.0292
 500 2000-01-10 05:30:00  1.0294  1.0290  1.0294  1.0292
 501 2000-01-10 05:45:00  1.0294  1.0287  1.0294  1.0290
 502 2000-01-10 06:00:00  1.0292  1.0287  1.0287  1.0289
 503 2000-01-10 06:15:00  1.0293  1.0287  1.0293  1.0292
 504 2000-01-10 06:30:00  1.0298  1.0290  1.0291  1.0292
 505 2000-01-10 06:45:00  1.0295  1.0291  1.0293  1.0295
 506 2000-01-10 07:00:00  1.0297  1.0289  1.0294  1.0291
 507 2000-01-10 07:15:00  1.0298  1.0285  1.0292  1.0289
 ..                  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
 927 2000-01-14 16:30:00  1.0142  1.0121  1.0130  1.0136
 928 2000-01-14 16:45:00  1.0140  1.0115  1.0135  1.0117
 929 2000-01-14 17:00:00  1.0134  1.0114  1.0117  1.0130
 930 2000-01-14 17:15:00  1.0138  1.0125  1.0129  1.0137
 931 2000-01-14 17:30:00  1.0144  1.0132  1.0135  1.0144
 932 2000-01-14 17:45:00  1.0146  1.0125  1.0142  1.0128
 933 2000-01-14 18:00:00  1.0152  1.0126  1.0128  1.0152
 934 2000-01-14 18:15:00  1.0156  1.0141  1.0152  1.0145
 935 2000-01-14 18:30:00  1.0147  1.0137  1.0144  1.0139
 936 2000-01-14 18:45:00  1.0150  1.0139  1.0139  1.0143
 937 2000-01-14 19:00:00  1.0148  1.0133  1.0143  1.0146
 938 2000-01-14 19:15:00  1.0151  1.0145  1.0147  1.0149
 939 2000-01-14 19:30:00  1.0152  1.0146  1.0149  1.0150
 940 2000-01-14 19:45:00  1.0156  1.0145  1.0149  1.0154
 941 2000-01-14 20:00:00  1.0157  1.0140  1.0154  1.0141
 942 2000-01-14 20:15:00  1.0147  1.0138  1.0141  1.0142
 943 2000-01-14 20:30:00  1.0147  1.0141  1.0142  1.0145
 944 2000-01-14 20:45:00  1.0157  1.0143  1.0146  1.0157
 945 2000-01-14 21:00:00  1.0155  1.0144  1.0154  1.0146
 946 2000-01-14 21:15:00  1.0147  1.0144  1.0145  1.0144
 947 2000-01-14 21:30:00  1.0145  1.0141  1.0145  1.0142
 948 2000-01-14 21:45:00  1.0145  1.0140  1.0141  1.0145
 949 2000-01-14 22:00:00  1.0145  1.0135  1.0144  1.0138
 950 2000-01-14 22:15:00  1.0140  1.0127  1.0140  1.0134
 951 2000-01-14 22:30:00  1.0132  1.0122  1.0131  1.0124
 952 2000-01-14 22:45:00  1.0124  1.0121  1.0122  1.0121
 953 2000-01-14 23:00:00  1.0133  1.0122  1.0122  1.0125
 954 2000-01-14 23:15:00  1.0128  1.0116  1.0128  1.0118
 955 2000-01-14 23:30:00  1.0122  1.0118  1.0119  1.0119
 956 2000-01-14 23:45:00  1.0123  1.0120  1.0121  1.0122

 [479 rows x 5 columns],
                 datebuff    High     Low    Open   Close
 957  2000-01-17 00:00:00  1.0131  1.0127  1.0129  1.0127
 958  2000-01-17 00:15:00  1.0127  1.0124  1.0126  1.0124
 959  2000-01-17 00:30:00  1.0124  1.0121  1.0123  1.0122
 960  2000-01-17 00:45:00  1.0122  1.0120  1.0121  1.0122
 961  2000-01-17 01:00:00  1.0131  1.0123  1.0123  1.0129
 962  2000-01-17 01:15:00  1.0138  1.0130  1.0133  1.0134
 963  2000-01-17 01:30:00  1.0137  1.0131  1.0134  1.0136
 964  2000-01-17 01:45:00  1.0140  1.0129  1.0137  1.0129
 965  2000-01-17 02:00:00  1.0135  1.0127  1.0128  1.0132
 966  2000-01-17 02:15:00  1.0134  1.0131  1.0133  1.0131
 967  2000-01-17 02:30:00  1.0135  1.0128  1.0130  1.0134
 968  2000-01-17 02:45:00  1.0137  1.0133  1.0134  1.0135
 969  2000-01-17 03:00:00  1.0136  1.0131  1.0133  1.0131
 970  2000-01-17 03:15:00  1.0137  1.0130  1.0133  1.0137
 971  2000-01-17 03:30:00  1.0140  1.0132  1.0140  1.0132
 972  2000-01-17 03:45:00  1.0135  1.0132  1.0135  1.0134
 973  2000-01-17 04:00:00  1.0136  1.0130  1.0136  1.0133
 974  2000-01-17 04:15:00  1.0134  1.0132  1.0134  1.0133
 975  2000-01-17 04:30:00  1.0135  1.0131  1.0132  1.0133
 976  2000-01-17 04:45:00  1.0134  1.0132  1.0132  1.0132
 977  2000-01-17 05:00:00  1.0136  1.0132  1.0134  1.0133
 978  2000-01-17 05:15:00  1.0136  1.0132  1.0132  1.0133
 979  2000-01-17 05:30:00  1.0136  1.0132  1.0136  1.0134
 980  2000-01-17 05:45:00  1.0137  1.0134  1.0136  1.0134
 981  2000-01-17 06:00:00  1.0136  1.0132  1.0134  1.0133
 982  2000-01-17 06:15:00  1.0138  1.0130  1.0134  1.0137
 983  2000-01-17 06:30:00  1.0142  1.0137  1.0138  1.0140
 984  2000-01-17 06:45:00  1.0145  1.0138  1.0140  1.0141
 985  2000-01-17 07:00:00  1.0148  1.0139  1.0142  1.0140
 986  2000-01-17 07:15:00  1.0145  1.0134  1.0139  1.0138
 ...                  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
 1407 2000-01-21 16:30:00  1.0080  1.0061  1.0075  1.0074
 1408 2000-01-21 16:45:00  1.0083  1.0066  1.0076  1.0070
 1409 2000-01-21 17:00:00  1.0080  1.0065  1.0071  1.0068
 1410 2000-01-21 17:15:00  1.0079  1.0065  1.0068  1.0069
 1411 2000-01-21 17:30:00  1.0080  1.0067  1.0069  1.0071
 1412 2000-01-21 17:45:00  1.0095  1.0070  1.0070  1.0094
 1413 2000-01-21 18:00:00  1.0102  1.0086  1.0095  1.0089
 1414 2000-01-21 18:15:00  1.0091  1.0079  1.0089  1.0086
 1415 2000-01-21 18:30:00  1.0094  1.0083  1.0085  1.0085
 1416 2000-01-21 18:45:00  1.0096  1.0085  1.0085  1.0092
 1417 2000-01-21 19:00:00  1.0095  1.0083  1.0091  1.0087
 1418 2000-01-21 19:15:00  1.0100  1.0085  1.0085  1.0095
 1419 2000-01-21 19:30:00  1.0102  1.0093  1.0096  1.0101
 1420 2000-01-21 19:45:00  1.0103  1.0096  1.0101  1.0096
 1421 2000-01-21 20:00:00  1.0099  1.0090  1.0095  1.0097
 1422 2000-01-21 20:15:00  1.0101  1.0093  1.0098  1.0095
 1423 2000-01-21 20:30:00  1.0099  1.0092  1.0094  1.0095
 1424 2000-01-21 20:45:00  1.0103  1.0093  1.0094  1.0103
 1425 2000-01-21 21:00:00  1.0100  1.0092  1.0098  1.0096
 1426 2000-01-21 21:15:00  1.0100  1.0092  1.0096  1.0098
 1427 2000-01-21 21:30:00  1.0099  1.0093  1.0094  1.0093
 1428 2000-01-21 21:45:00  1.0097  1.0088  1.0092  1.0088
 1429 2000-01-21 22:00:00  1.0091  1.0084  1.0087  1.0088
 1430 2000-01-21 22:15:00  1.0094  1.0086  1.0091  1.0088
 1431 2000-01-21 22:30:00  1.0092  1.0084  1.0085  1.0085
 1432 2000-01-21 22:45:00  1.0094  1.0086  1.0088  1.0094
 1433 2000-01-21 23:00:00  1.0097  1.0089  1.0097  1.0091
 1434 2000-01-21 23:15:00  1.0101  1.0090  1.0090  1.0101
 1435 2000-01-21 23:30:00  1.0089  1.0089  1.0089  1.0089
 1436 2000-01-21 23:45:00  1.0087  1.0087  1.0087  1.0087

 [480 rows x 5 columns],
```

**Update 1**
for the first point, i have tried the below code, but i keep getting 'ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions'
 weeks is array of 986 arrays, each is around 478-480, the window size is 10

```
X = np.array([])
y = np.array([])
for i in range(0, len(weeks)):
    z = weeks[i]
    z = np.asarray(z)
    z = z[:,[1,2,3,4,5]]
    X = np.append(X,[np.atleast_3d(np.array([z[index:index + window_size] for index in range(0, z.shape[0] - window_size)]))],axis=0) # The inputs to a predictor
    y = np.append(y,[z[window_size:,[4]]],axis=0)
```

**Update 2**
Finally solved the first issue by using python's lists instead of numpy arrays.

```
window_size = 10
X = []
y = []

for i in range(0, len(weeks)):
    z = weeks[i]
    z = np.asarray(z)
    z = z[:,[1,2,3,4,5]]
    X.append([np.atleast_3d(np.array([z[index:index + window_size] for index in range(0, z.shape[0] - window_size)]))]) # The inputs to a predictor
    y.append([z[window_size:,[4]]])
```

And as per the keras documentation, it seem like the stateful is what i am looking for:
stateful: Boolean (default False). If True, the last state for each sample at index i in a batch will be used as initial state for the sample of index i in the following batch.

**Update 3**
Now i am trying to work with the below model - using stateful - the issue is in setting batch_input_shape, as it requires the batch size, which i need to change in every stateful iteration or it will get the below error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [276,1] vs. [277,1]
```

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM

neurons = 50
batch_size = len(X)
window_size = X[0][0].shape[1]
nb_features = X[0][0].shape[2]

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(neurons, batch_input_shape=(len(X[0][0]), window_size, nb_features), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])


for i in range(batch_size):
    model.fit(X[i], y[i], epochs=1, batch_size=len(X[i][0]), verbose=0, shuffle=False)
```